# How to truncate the streaming output of a redirect?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a process that outputs a line for every progress update (sidenote: it does clear/replace the line, no pure newline break).

I want to save the latest line of that process to an output file or truncate the output file to keep the size manageable.

At the moment I have
`genrtr > genrtr.log`
and with a cron I tried to use `> genrtr.log` but it doesn't work. Also `rm genrtr.log` doesn't help because then the process stops updating the file.

I understand why those don't work, but wonder how to restructure it so it fits my needs.

Tried `genrtr | sed -ne '$w genrtr.log'` but then it waits for the process to end before writing to the file.

Clarifications:
The process produces output every 1 second and unless the server crashes the process will keep running for ever.

Comment: What exactly is `genrtr`? Can you edit it?

Comment: It's a program written in C that I can edit but have almost no knowledge on C and I would rather not mess with that for maintenance purposes.

Comment: Maybe [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) can help you? I do not have enough experience with that, so I don't know whether that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i was wondering whats the frequency of the run ? ....

try tee to redirect output to the logfile , its a utility often used to make a copy of the strem and redirect that copy into the output file

```
use : 
  command | tee command_result.log
```

you could have a monitor function in a wrapper script that invokes this program which will delete the top 10 lines after some intreval ....... this way your log file wont get more than a few KB

also if there are useless spaces in between you could use translate "tr" utility to squeeze ...
 example :

```
Nitin@Kaizen ~
$ df -h | head -1
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

Nitin@Kaizen ~
$ df -h | head -1 | tr -s ' '
    Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on   *** note the squeeze in space
```

hope this helps

Comment: I didn't know of tee, but it seems to have the same effect as `>` while it adds data while the process is running, when I `> command_result.log` the file is unaffected.

Comment: what tee does is that it duplicates the stream , but here it might help :: command | tee lofile  2>&1 > /dev/null .... this way you get a seperate copy of the log that you can manipulate in your wrapper script to extract usefiull info .... or whatever , the dev/null is a special file that dosent grow .... so your space issue is also managed this way.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try. The easiest is ti just print the last lines of the file:

```
tail genrtr.log
```

Then, once the process finished delete the log file. Another option, would be to periodically overwrite the file.

- Launch the process in the background:

  ```
  genrtr > genrtr.log &
  ```
- Overwrite the contents of the logfile:

  ```
  echo > genrtr.log
  ```

The file is now truncated but will continue to be updated by `gentr` so the next update report will be written to it. You could automate this, for example, truncating the file if it gets larger than 1MB:

```
while true; 
  do if [ $(stat -c%s genrtr.log) -gt 1000000 ]; then 
    tail genrt.log > /tmp/foo && cat /tmp/foo > genrt.log; 
     fi;
done
```

That little scriptlet will run until you stop it (`while true;`), and every time that genrtr.log is larger than one MB, it will keep the last few lines and delete the rest of the file.

---

UPDATE:

As Scott very correctly pointed out below, if your output contains `\r` to clear the line, `tail` will not work as expected. This, however, should:

```
while true; 
  do if [ $(stat -c%s genrtr.log) -gt 1000000 ]; then 
    tail genrt.log | perl -pe 's/.+\r(.+)/$1\n/' > /tmp/foo && cat /tmp/foo > genrt.log; 
     fi;
done
```

The perl command deletes everything before the last `\r` and prints the last "line" (the data after the `\r` and a newline. The result should be that the list line is kept, the rest of the file is cleared and the file continues to be populated.

Comment: Unfortunately the ` > ` redirect doesn't seem to allow any modification to the target file while the process is running and `genrtr` will run for ever.

Comment: @terdon: The question says that the program doesn’t end the update messages with newlines, but rather with escape sequences to erase and re-use the same line on the screen.  Do you believe that `tail` will behave intelligently with that input?  (Maybe with `tail -400c`, to get the last 400 characters and hope that that is at least the last five lines.)

Comment: @Sev: We seem to be having a failure to communicate.  Are you saying that, if you type `genrtr > genrtr.log`, the output still comes out on the screen, and `genrtr.log` is empty?  If so, what happens if you type `genrtr 2> genrtr.log`?

Comment: `genrtr > genrtr.log` doesn't show output on the screen, it redirects the output correctly to the file, but while the process is running, you can't amend the file successfully (tried `> genrtr.log` and similar)

I tried `genrtr 2> genrtr.log` and it saved the top info text of the initial output on the file, but the main repeating progress update text shows up on the screen instead.

Comment: @Sev: Belatedly, welcome to Super User.  For your information, when you respond to a comment (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by “@”, as in “@Scott”.  That way he gets notified.  You can abbreviate, and you can mention multiple names, as in “@George, @Scott”.  See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [the **Comment formatting** section](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of the Markdown Editing Help page.

Comment: @Scott, assuming the program is using `\r`, if there are no real new lines (`\n`) `tail` will just print the entire file. Still works, and might be faster if there _are_ new lines.

Comment: @Sev, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is going to be very tricky to do without either modifying `genrtrc`
or writing a new program.  If you’re more comfortable doing the latter, I suggest this outline:

> `int   c;`
>    `FILE  *fp;`
>
> `fp = fopen(`*log_file*`, "w");`
>    `if (fp == NULL)` *(Handle errors)*
>    `while ((c = getc()) != EOF)`
>    `{`
>        `putchar(c);`
>        `if (c ==`*escape sequence that ends a line*`)`
>        `{`
>            `fflush(fp);     //`You should probably check for errors here, too.
>            `rewind(fp);`
>        `}`
>        `else`
>            `putc(c, fp);`
>    `}`

This acts like a combination of `tee` and `tail` -- reading standard input, and writing it to standard output and a file -- with the difference that it keeps only the last line in the file. 
Then you would run

> `genrtr |`*the_above_program*

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

> At the moment I have `genrtr > genrtr.log` and with a cron I tried to use `> genrtr.log` but it doesn't work.

This approach can easily be fixed by using `genrtr >> …` instead of `genrtr > …` (while still using `>` in cron to truncate the file).

The difference is explained in [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1342490/432690) which can be summarized by the following statement:

> `>>` is essentially "always seek to end of file" while `>` maintains a pointer to the last written location.

Read the linked answer, it totally matches your case.

---

#### Side note

> Also `rm genrtr.log` doesn't help because then the process stops updating the file.

Strictly it *does not* stop updating the file. The file gets unlinked from the directory, but it's still open, [still written to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146929/108618), it still consumes more and more space in the filesystem.

Any new file is a different file even if it takes the same pathname. The process does not update the new file because it never opens it, it doesn't even notice it. The file descriptor used by the process still leads to the old (deleted) file.